# Button's animation on press happens not as required

Tags: flutter

There is a custom button made of this

```
RawMaterialButton(
     constraints: BoxConstraints.tightFor(width: 12),
     onPressed: null,
     child: IconButton(
     icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel, color: kActiveColor),
        onPressed: () => state.clear(),
     ),
),
```

But the animation on press happens not on the button and looks odd, how to fix it?

[image]

Comment: What kind of result do you want to achieve? If you only want the `IconButton`, `RawMaterialButton` is not needed here.

Comment: @mkobuolys RawMaterialButton just helps to achive the correct position of the IconButton, if I remove the RawMaterialButton, a gap between right egde of the screen and the IconButton a little bit bigger then it nedeed

Comment: Showing the full code of where you are trying to align this button would help. In general, wrapping a button inside another button just to align it is not a solution, for sure.

Comment: @mkobuolys https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67555976/iconbutton-takes-too-much-space-to-the-edge-of-screen

Comment: So your question is more about the alignment issue and not about the button animation problems?

Comment: @rozerro I think you have another question to solve the gap issue. I posted an answer there, do check it out.

Answer (score -1):

Can you add these lines to avoid splash effect.

```
splashColor: Colors.transparent,  
highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
hoverColor: Colors.transparent,
```

Comment: It is working can you please check this link - https://dartpad.dev/1a28bdd9203250d3226cc25d512579ec?null_safety=true ?

Comment: there is only a default flutter example

Comment: Have you tried running it ? img ref - https://imgur.com/6Uxa19X