# IconButton takes too much space to the edge of screen

Tags: flutter, margin, iconbutton

IconButton takes too much space to the edge of screen.
This is how I made it:

```dart
return Scaffold(
  body: Column(
    children: [
      Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Column(
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [ 
          Row(
             children: <Widget>[
               Expanded(child: Input()),
               IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
                onPressed: () {},
               ),
             ],
        ), ...
```

**It looks like:**
[image]

How to fix it to make icon closer to the margin edge?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `constraints` parameter on the `IconButton`.

You can use it like this.

```
constraints: BoxConstraints.tight(Size(24, 24))
```

Information on how to easily solve these problems can be obtained by checking the internal documentation of your `IconButton`.

If you `cmd + click` on the `IconButton` and check it's build method, you will see that it is using a `ConstrainedBox` to decide it's size based on some factors.

One such factor is the `constraints` that we pass to the Widget.

Answer (score 3):

I usually use `GestureDetector` or `InkWell` for such cases, as they offer more size adjustments if given container as child. You can give `Icon` as child to either of these.

```
InkWell(
     child: const Icon(Icons.cancel),
     onTap: () {},
)
```

Or

```
InkWell(
     child: Container(child : Icon(Icons.cancel), height: 24.0, width: 24.0),
     onTap: () {},
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set padding to zero?

```
IconButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
      ...
    );
```

Comment: try to make icon size smaller, I think that its constraints are bigger than the icon size.

Comment: the icon is small enaugh

Comment: when you make it smaller does it align to center?

Answer (score 0):

You can manipulate it's size and space taken with 4 parameters :

```
 IconButton(
  padding: EdgeInsets.zero,
  iconSize: 20,
  splashRadius: 16,
  onPressed: () {
    /// do sth
  },
  icon: const Icon(
  Icons.edit, color: Colors.orange)
)
```